# SelectMany on object property and then saving result back to property causes stackoverflow

Tags: c#

I have a simple class, `NumberCollection`, that has a property `Numbers` of type `List<int>`.

```cs
public class NumberCollection
{
    public IEnumerable<int> Numbers { get; set; }
}
```

I created a list of `NumberCollection`:

```cs
var list = new List<NumberCollection>
{
    new NumberCollection
    {
        Numbers=new List<int>{1,2,3},
    },
    new NumberCollection
    {
        Numbers=new List<int>{4,5,6},
    },
};
```

Now I want to select just the first element of `list` and save the concatenated `Numbers` of all `NumberCollections` to the first element. I ran this code:

```cs
var singleCollection = list.FirstOrDefault();
singleCollection.Numbers = list.SelectMany(c => c.Numbers);
```

It compiles and runs fine, but trying to access any members of `singleCollection.Numbers` crashes the debugger. Evaluating `singleCollection.Numbers.ElementAt(0)` in the immediate window gives a stackoverflow exception. What's going on here?

Comment: Could you try `list.SelectMany(c => c.Numbers).ToList()`?

Comment: @ilkerkaran That works. Can you explain why?

Comment: `ToList` actually snapshots the collection and creates new list from it. `SelectMany` returns `IEnumerable`. Meaning, it refers itself over and over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd get the same behavior from this code:

```
IEnumerable<int> a = new[] { 1 };
a = a.SelectMany(_ => a);
a.First();
```

Since `SelectMany()` uses deferred execution, its lambda expression is not evaluated until `a.First()` is called. By that point, the `a` that is referenced in its lambda is not pointing to `new[] { 1 }` anymore. Instead, it's pointing at `a.SelectMany(_ => a)`, which in turn can only be resolved by iterating over `a`. Hence, there's a circular reference, and the call stack goes deeper and deeper until the dotnet runtime gives up with a Stack Overflow exception.

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a circular reference (hence the stackoverflow).

You're assigning the `first item` in list to `singleCollection`, then trying to reassign the first item's number into its own `Numbers` property. You'll need to either add a new reference via `ToList`, or add just the value via `Concat`.

```
    var singleCollection = list.FirstOrDefault();
    singleCollection.Numbers = list.SelectMany(c => c.Numbers).ToList() ;
    Console.WriteLine(singleCollection.Numbers.ElementAt(0));

    var singleCollection2 = list.FirstOrDefault();
    singleCollection2.Numbers.Concat(list.SelectMany(c => c.Numbers)); 
    Console.WriteLine(singleCollection2.Numbers.ElementAt(0));
```

Edit, you can also create a new 'referenced' list initially as well by using Select then creating a new instance of NumberCollection.

```
  var singleCollection3 = list.Select(x => new NumberCollection { Numbers = x.Numbers.ToList() }).FirstOrDefault();
    singleCollection3.Numbers = list.SelectMany(c => c.Numbers);
    Console.WriteLine(singleCollection3.Numbers.ElementAt(0));
```

**Important to note**: With SelectMany, you are using deferred execution. This means that the evaluation of the expression will be delayed until its value is actually used. This is why the StackOverflow doesn't happen until you actually try and access a number.

Comment: It may be important to mention is that `SelectMany()`, like most LINQ operators, uses deferred execution.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior how does that affect things?

Comment: OP added comment, thanks for the suggestion @StriplingWarrior

Comment: @stellr42: It was too hard to explain in a comment, so I added my own answer. Hopefully that makes it clear.